# Convert an array of integers into a string of HEX

Tags: perl

I have an array with some integers, and I would like to convert it to a string in hexadecimal format. This is the code I use, and it works fine.  I just wonder if there is a simpler way to do it.

```
my @arr = get_tw() ; ##array of integer

for(my $i=0;$i<@arr;$i++){ 

  $arr[$i]= sprintf('%02x',$arr[$i]); ##overwrite with the hex value

} 

my $string  = join('',@arr); ##build a string from a array
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using pack/unpack:

```
my $string = join '', unpack('H*', pack('c*',@arr));
```

Answer (score 5):

[map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).  This avoids the intermediate array variable, if you don't need it for anything else.

```
my $string = join '', map { sprintf '%02x', $_ } get_tw();
```

Full example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub get_tw { return 8 .. 15 }

my $string = join '', map { sprintf '%02x', $_ } get_tw();
print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
08090a0b0c0d0e0f
```

Answer (score 4):

The string repetition operator with the `sprintf` template:

```
my $string = sprintf "%02x" x @arr, @arr
```